# Generating Very Little Doxygen Documentation

Tags: c, cmake, doxygen

I am trying to generate Doxygen documentation for the very first time in a simple C project. Unfortunately, I am only having limited success. I have tried reading the documentation that Doxygen provides (https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/starting.html) on getting started. However, it is not very clear to me.

I can generate some Doxygen documentation from my small C project. The Doxygen documentation that I do generate is limited to a struct I created in `Michaels_Criterion_tests.c` called `structOfSignals`. For `structOfSignals`, I see my brief statement in "Class Lists/Class Index" along with there being no parameters or returns (I basically copied this from how I document my functions).

For all other documentation in my header files or functions in my .c files, I do not see my brief comments (though Doxygen clearly does acknowledge my header files since it has put them under "File List").

I believe my issue stems from one of three possibilities:

1. One or more configuration options in my `Doxyfile` are incorrect.
2. My `CmakeLists.txt` is incorrect (a strong likelihood).
3. Both 1. and 2.

I have kept my `Doxyfile` with mostly the defaults. The few exceptions are:

- Assigning string values to `PROJECT_NAME`, `PROJECT_NUMBER`, and `PROJECT_BRIEF`.
- I assigned `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = "output"` (output files are being created in my `output` directory).
- Changed `JAVADOC_BANNER` from `NO` to `YES`. I knew this would be a problem with my style of comments if I did not change this value.

Here are the contents of my several files:

The `Doxyfile` file is too large to post but hopefully the above list of changes make it clear it is mostly the defualt values. I am using version 1.9.1 of Doxygen.

**CmakeLists.txt:**
NOTE: I comment out the c and header files of `Michaels_Criterion_tests` and `fibonacci` because that is only code I care about when I unit test. A future goal is to have a conditional statement which will toggle to include or exclude those files based on wether or not I am trying to unit test. But for right now, I just want to have things work with a smaller unber of files.

```
#Minimum version of CMake required
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(mainProject) #name this to whatever you'd like 

# Set C standard
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

# Locate Doxygen
find_package(Doxygen REQUIRED)

# Locate Criterion
#find_package(criterion REQUIRED)

# Set input directory
set(DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
#set(DOXYGEN_OUTPUT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/docs)

# Set source and header files
set(SOURCES
    ${DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR}/main.c
    ${DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR}/timer.c
    #${DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR}/Michaels_Criterion_tests.c
    ${DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR}/signalHandler.c
    #${DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR}/fibonacci.c
)

set(HEADERS
    ${DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR}/timer.h
    #${DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR}/Michaels_Criterion_tests.h
    ${DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR}/signalHandler.h
    #${DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR}/fibonacci.h
)

# Configure Doxygen
set(DOXYGEN_CONFIG ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output/Doxyfile)
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile ${DOXYGEN_CONFIG} @ONLY)

# Add executable target
add_executable(mainProject ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

# Link with Criterion
#target_link_libraries(mainProject criterion)

# Add a target to generate API documentation with Doxygen
add_custom_target(
    doc ALL DEPENDS mainProject
    COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${DOXYGEN_CONFIG}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen"
    VERBATIM
)
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>               //for clock() and CLOCKS_PER_SEC
#include "signalHandler.h"
#include "timer.h"

//@file main.c


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int raiseResult;
    void (*prev_handler)(int);
    sig_atomic_t signaled = 0;      //Debug testing only. Remove later.

    printf("Hello, World!\n");

    //Register the signal handler
    prev_handler = signal(TEST_SIGNAL_51, sigHandler);

    //call the timey function
    raiseResult = timey(1, TEST_SIGNAL_51);

    //debug
    printf("raiseResult =%d.\n",raiseResult );

    return 0;

}
```

**sigHandler.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include "signalHandler.h"

//sig_atomic_t signaled = 0;      //Debug testing only. Remove later.

/************************************************************************************************************
The function is a signal handler.
Parameters:
    int sig - The signal's number
Returns:
    N/A
************************************************************************************************************/
void sigHandler(int sig)
{
    //signaled = 1;

    //Switch statement to handle all signals
    switch(sig) {
        case TEST_SIGNAL_50:
            printf("Case 50 has been matched.\n");
            //LOG AND DO STUFF...
            break;
        case TEST_SIGNAL_51:
            printf("Case 51 has been matched.\n");
            //LOG AND DO STUFF...
            break;
        case TEST_SIGNAL_52:
            printf("Case 52 has been matched.\n");
            //LOG AND DO STUFF...
            break;
        case SIGINT:
            printf("SIGINT Case has been matched.\n");
            //LOG AND DO STUFF...
            break;
        default:    //Raised signal is not a match
            printf("Raised signal %d is not a match.\n", sig);
            //Probably just log an error and hope we can ignore without blowing up??
            break;
    }
}
```

**sigHandler.h**

```
#ifndef SIGNAL_HANDLER_H
#define SIGNAL_HANDLER_H

#define TEST_SIGNAL_50 50       //PLACEHOLDER
#define TEST_SIGNAL_51 51       //PLACEHOLDER
#define TEST_SIGNAL_52 52       //PLACEHOLDER


//Function declarations
void sigHandler(int sig);

#endif /* SIGNAL_HANDLER_H */
```

**timer.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>               //for clock() and CLOCKS_PER_SEC
#include <signal.h>
#include "timer.h"
#include "signalHandler.h"

//@file timer.c

int timer(int trigger){
    clock_t start = clock(), difference;
    int msec = 0;
    int raiseResult;       //Holds return value of raise(). raise() returns zero if successful and a nonzero value if unsuccessful.

    do{
        //printf("This is a message\n");                    //Debug only                
        difference = clock() - start;                       //The difference between the start of the clock and "now".
        msec = difference * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;          //CLOCKS_PER_SEC is defined in time.h. Clock ticks per second (system dependent)
    } while(msec < trigger);

    printf("Time taken %d seconds %d milliseconds\n", msec/1000, msec%1000);

    //raiseResult = raise(SIGINT);
    //raiseResult = raise(SIGUSR1);
    raiseResult = raise(TEST_SIGNAL_51);

    return raiseResult;
}



/***********************************************************************************************************
* This function is a timer which raises the signal after trigger milliseconds have elapsed
* Parameters:
*     @param int trigger - The time, in milliseconds, in which this timer should trigger an alarm.
*     @param int signalToRaise - The signal that will be raised once this timer raises its alarm.
* Returns:
*     @return int - This is the return result of raise(); zero if successful and a nonzero value if unsuccessful.
************************************************************************************************************/
int timey(int trigger, int signalToRaise){
    clock_t start = clock(), difference;
    int msec = 0;
    int raiseResult;       //Holds return value of raise(). raise() returns zero if successful and a nonzero value if unsuccessful.

    do{
        //printf("This is a message\n");                    //Debug only  
        difference = clock() - start;                       //The difference between the start of the clock and "now".
        msec = difference * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;          //CLOCKS_PER_SEC is defined in time.h. Clock ticks per second (system dependent)
    } while(msec < trigger);

    printf("Time taken %d seconds %d milliseconds\n", msec/1000, msec%1000);
    printf("About to raise signal %d\n", signalToRaise);

    raiseResult = raise(signalToRaise);

    return raiseResult;
}
```

**timer.h**

```
#ifndef TIMER_H
#define TIMER_H

//@file CASCTimer.c

//Function declarations
int timer(int trigger);

/***********************************************************************************************************
* @brief This function is a timer which raises the signal after trigger milliseconds have elapsed
* Parameters:
*     @param int trigger - The time, in milliseconds, in which this timer should trigger an alarm.
*     @param int signalToRaise - The signal that will be raised once this timer raises its alarm.
* Returns:
*     @return int - This is the return result of raise(); zero if successful and a nonzero value if unsuccessful.
************************************************************************************************************/
int timey(int trigger, int signalToRaise);

#endif /* TIMER_H */
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: A [mre] would be great, along with expected and actual output. Separate the Doxygen problems from the CMake problems and ask one question at a time (chances are you will solve your problems in the process). Doxygen only picks up special comments such as `///` or `/** ... */` so anything in regular C comments (like `//@file CASCTimer.c`) is lost.

Comment: Noteworthy Doxyfile configurations: _OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C_, configs starting with _EXTRACT_ in the section "_Build related configuration options_". If you set the relevant options to _YES_, doxygen will generate documentation for each and every statement/declaration in your header and source files, even if they are undocumented.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük your comment was correct! If you want to make it an answer, I would be happy to mark it as correct. :)

Comment: You wrote: "The Doxyfile file is too large to post " but doxygen has the possibility  tyo show only the differences with the default settings by means of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noteworthy *Doxyfile* configurations:

- `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C`
- configs starting with `EXTRACT` in the section *"Build related configuration options"*. If you set the relevant options to `YES`, doxygen will generate documentation for each and every statement/declaration in your header and source files, even if they are undocumented.

Comment: Please show the doxygen settings you used  different from the default settings by means of `doxygen -x Doxyfile` as I suspect that what you write is not the complete story (I don't think `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C=YES` does the trick but `EXTRACT_ALL=YES`).

Comment: @albert I honestly don't know which setting was the right one for the OP. I initially wrote a comment about some **noteworthy** configuration settings, the OP said it was a 'correct' (to be modest, lets say a good/helpful) response (which presumably helped to solve the issue) and asked me to write it as an answer.